# Reset Picker Display Value in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I have a form that has a Picker Element that the user can choose an option. Using the MVVM approach I am able to retrieve the value and reset the Picker option. However the text displayed on the screen is not being removed.

This is the XAML code snippet of the Picker:

```
<Picker Title="Choose A Category"
                        x:Name="PickerCategory" 
                        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Type}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding CategorySelection}"
                        SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectIndex}"
                        SelectedIndexChanged="PickerCategory_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
```

This is the ViewModel to reset the Picker:

```
class SellPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public SellPageViewModel()
    {
        Vehicle = new Vehicle();
        SaveVehicleCommand = new Command(SaveVehicle);
        SetNewCommand = new Command(SetNew);
        SetUsedCommand = new Command(SetUsed);
    }

    private Vehicle vehicle;

    public Vehicle Vehicle
    {
        get { return vehicle; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref vehicle, value);
            Console.WriteLine("Vehicle details entered");
        }
    }

    private object categorySelection;

    public object CategorySelection
    {
        get { return categorySelection; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref categorySelection, value);
            Category catToInt = (Category)value;
            if (value != null)
                Vehicle.CategoryId = catToInt.Id;
            
        }
    }

    private int selectIndex;
    public int SelectIndex
    {
        get { return selectIndex; }
        set
        {
            if (value != -1)
                SetProperty(ref selectIndex, value);
        }
    }



    public Command SetNewCommand { get; }
    public Command SetUsedCommand { get; }
    public Command SaveVehicleCommand { get; }

    void SetNew()
    {
        Vehicle.Condition = "New";
    }

    void SetUsed()
    {
        Vehicle.Condition = "Used";
    }
    async void SaveVehicle()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Save Button Clicked");
        Console.WriteLine(Vehicle.Title);
        Console.WriteLine(Vehicle.Price);
        Console.WriteLine(Vehicle.CategoryId);
        Console.WriteLine(Vehicle.Condition);


        SelectIndex = 0;

        Vehicle = new Vehicle();
        
        
    }
}
```

So after resetting the Index for the picker, the value resets but the Title for the value stays:

[image]

How can I make this field reset to the Placeholder text that was there before the user selects an item?

Comment: the default value of SelectedIndex is -1, not 0

Comment: I tried -1 too and it did not work.

Comment: `CategorySelection = null;` ?

Comment: @Cfun I tried that too

Comment: @Cfun with your help I figured it out though. Ill make the answer a post

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple solve after suggestion from @CFun:

I set:

```
CategorySelection = new Category();
```

The SelectIndex was not necessary in the code to perform this function. So it can be removed from both the ViewModel and XAML page.